# How to generate 5 random 3 digit numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, random

There's this exercise that asks me to generate 5 random 3 digit numbers. The exercise requests that I generate those random numbers by using digits that are inputted by the user. Despite me not knowing how to explain, I could try to give an example:

```
std::cout << "a = ";
std::cin >> a;
std::cout << "b = ";
std::cin >> b;
std::cout << "c = ";
std::cin >> c;
```

I'll input the value of these integers (that have to be smaller than 10). Let's say a = 5; b = 3; c = 7.
I need to generate 5 random 3 digit numbers using the values of a,b,c that the user puts in. I am allowed to use a, b and c only once when generating that number.
Using the example above, this is how the numbers should look like: 537, 375, 357, 753, 735 (just an example, there are more possibilities). No numbers like 557, 533 etc.
Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search term: Permutation.

Comment: @user4581301sorry for tagging, but how would you do it to limit exactly 5 numbers?

Comment: Count them. If the number of permutations you have produced is five, stop making more.

Comment: Note: Don't think of these as numbers. Think of them as strings of symbols. It will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try randomly multiplying the three numbers by 1, 10, and 100. Then add the three. For example:

```
5 * 1 = 5
3 * 10 = 30
7 * 100 = 700

5 + 30 + 700 = 735
```

This will guarantee a valid permutation.